# The application has disappeared without a reason after the dev. account deactivation

Tags: facebook, permissions

I had an application on developers.facebook.com
I've been submitting for the Facebook permissions for a long time and there were no problems. But on the 'stream live api permission' approval I've got a rejection with the reason that my application doesn't need this permission. I've reported a bug and the support told me that I need this permission, I've submitted for approval again. During the approval my account has been deactivated and I was informed to change the account name according to the provided documents.
I changed the name, but the application has disappeared. Support can't tell why this has happened, but I need it back, because there are already a lot of approved permissions. Maybe some of you can tell why this has happened and how to restore the application.

The id of the app is: 867148823415081

Best regards, hope we'll find the solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Go check https://developers.facebook.com/appeal and see if it listed there.

Comment: 'There are no apps available for you to recover. If you don't see the app you're looking for, it means we're not able to restore that app.' and no restrictions.
Looks like this app has never existed. Any ideas?

Comment: File a bug report and ask them to please look into what happened to that app id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug from the Facebook side. The question to the developers.facebook.com/bugs has helped. They just reactivated the admin rights.